# In the installer, when splitting an existing partition, which side is which?

Tags: installation, partitioning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Installing Ubuntu with Windows, which is left and right when allocating space?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/150550/installing-ubuntu-with-windows-which-is-left-and-right-when-allocating-space)

I am about to install Ubuntu alongside windows. I've reached a setup screen which has a movable partition bar, with one side for Windows and the other side for Ubuntu. But I cannot see any obvious thing telling me which partition is which. So can someone tell me what the left side is and what the right side is?