# Which side indicates the Ubuntu partition in Automatic partition resizing window in Installation

Tags: partitioning, dual-boot, resize

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In the installer, when splitting an existing partition, which side is which?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138510/in-the-installer-when-splitting-an-existing-partition-which-side-is-which)

I am trying to install Ubuntu 12.04 alongside Windows 7. I get to the "Automatic partition resizing slider" window, and I see two partitions that I can resize by dragging.  However, I am bit confused, will Ubuntu be installed on the left side or the right side?

I need this because, I want to allocate a certain amount of disk space to the Ubuntu partition, but I have no idea which side ,left or right, is the Ubuntu partition.  There is no label.  I am following [the installation instructions here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot). There is not help in the instructions either.

The installation instruction says "Specify the size of the new partition by dragging the slider at the bottom of the window" , without providing any hints about which will be the Ubuntu partition.

I've looked all over but cannot find an answer to this question.