# Will installing Ubuntu erase my existing OS?

Tags: installation

When installing Ubuntu does it erase the other O.S.?

Comment: For detailed info on installing, once you have made your decision, refer to http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

Not if you don't want it to. Boot in to live CD when ask click "Install Ubuntu" then "install side by side with Windows." Set HDD sizes for both OSes, and install.

When you boot you will see a boot loader called grub with about 5 options. One is Ubuntu; one is Windows; the rest are verious safe modes for Ubuntu. Choose your os and off you go.

Or mount a live CD in Windows and click Wubi to create Ubuntu as a windows program if you just want to try it out.

Answer (score 0):

it depends on how you install Ubuntu. You can install it side by side (which is a dual setup) or overwrite the other OS or if you are using Windows even install through Windows with WUBI without nearly changing anything to the OS at all. If you use a live CD to install Ubuntu, it lists you the available options on how to install Ubuntu (including not erasing the preinstalled OS).
If you are just curious and want to test Ubuntu safely, I'd advise you using WUBI to install it as a Windows application or to run the live CD without installing Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

When installing Ubuntu from a Live CD, or USB, you have the option of partitioning the operating system, you also have the option of wiping the operating system and replacing it if preferred.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the option, you selected during installation. There are *(most of the time)* three options in the installation phase. "Install Ubuntu side by side", "Erase previous OS and install Ubuntu", and "Manual Partitioning". If you select "Install Ubuntu side by side" option, it will not erase the old OS.

If you select, "Install Ubuntu side by side" option, Don't confuse with the slider. The Ubuntu partition is the right one. So, make size accordingly. You might see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/156993/61218) to see the partitioning side.