# Installing 12.04 alongside windows 7

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot

Trying to install Ubuntu 12.04 alongside windows 7 home. However when I get the installation option it says that there are already multiple os installed and **it dosn't give **me the option to install Ubuntu alongside windows.****

The problem is that I have no other OS installed.

No my question hasnt been answered at
Installing Ubuntu with Windows, which is left and right when allocating space? 5 answers

My question has nothing to do with which is left and right when allocating space?

Please read question before posting an unrelated answer

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://askubuntu.com/questions/150550/installing-ubuntu-with-windows-which-is-left-and-right-when-allocating-space

Comment: Thanks but sorry im not even givin the option this user have

Answer (score 1):

I fixed my problem.
I deleted and merged all partitions. This has fixed the problem I now have the option to 
install Ubuntu alongside windows 7.

The extra partitions I had were 
Recovery(D:) "not user about the letters
HP_Tools(F:)

I hope this can help anyone who is/was having similar problem

Comment: Glad you fixed your problem. Do not forget to mark your answer as 'accepted' to help future users that have the same problem as you.

Answer (score 0):

During installation process, there is a screen with proposal of various options (i.e.: Replace windows, install alongside windows, etc.).

One of those options is *"Something else"* (literally), which in further steps, allows you to create your own partition setup.

Comment: Ive have looked at that option but was hoping someone could come up with possible reason why I dont have the install alongside option in first place. 
In windows under computer there is local disk(C:) Recovery(D:) and HP_TOOLS(E:) could these be conusing ubuntu ?

Comment: This might be THE reason; particulary the HP recovery partition, which is bootable. I don't remeber all the installer options exactly. I always do my own setup, to make sure the installer does'n destroy existing partitions.

Comment: When i do click (something else) it gives me this info

Comment: I cant make new lines it all comes out strung together
When i do click (something else) it gives me this info
/dev/sda  
/dev/sda1 ntfs    208(size)  69mb(used)
/dev/sda2 ntfs   480450mb(size) 125729mb(used)
/dev/sda3 ntfs   151816mn(size)  13488(used)
/dev/sda4/ fat32  4260mb         3098mb
Device for boot loaded installation:
/dev/sda ata toshiba mk5076gs(500.gb)
/dev/sda1 Windows 7 (loader)
/dev/sda2 Windows 7 (loader) <----could this be the problem?
/dev/sda3 Windos recovers Enviroment (loader)
/dev/sda4

Comment: well it says i have two windows 7 (loaders) could this be the problem?

Comment: Please help im at my wits end

Comment: would a reward temp someone into helping me fix this issue